# Saving results of a for loop filter to a new csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, split

I have a csv file that I am trying to split into multiple files, with each file corresponding to a single value in a particular column. The csv has the following format:

```
Site Photo OtherInfo OtherInfo2
1B   1     aaaa      3421
1B   2     fdjj      4821
2B   1     kdjs      2899
2B   2     klsj      1282
3B   1     adjsf     1782
3B   2     eewi      1832
```

Site is always a string.

I have a schedule (list) of which sites are going to be used this year, and I would like to extract these sites from the csv, saving each site into an individual csv file named e.g. 1B.csv
I would like to split this into a 1B.csv and 2B.csv

Schedule format:

```
Site
1B
2B
.
.
.
```

I have tried the following loop

```
import pandas as pd
Site_List = (list of sites for this year)
image_df = (see above data structure)

def split_csv(image_df, SiteList):
    for site in SiteList:
        file_name = site +'.csv'
        csv_site = image_df[image_df['Site'] == site]
        csv_site.to_csv(file_name, index=False, sep = ",")

split_csv(image_df, SiteList)
```

When I run `split_csv` I get no error messages, but there aren't any files created either.  What am I missing here? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for your help.

SiteList is the name of the schedule.

**Edit**

The schedule file wasn't reading properly. I have fixed this error, and now execution of the script returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in split_csv
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Initially I thought this was because `schedule` was stored as a series. Converting it to a list did not fix this. Is the for loop reading the index value when it performs `site in schedule`? So that instead of reading '1B' for the first item in site it pulls 0 and tries to concatenate 0 +.csv? I tried modifying the function to convert `site` to a string, but I still get the same error.

The function as it stands now:

I have edited the original variables to better match what my actual function is, so that it is easier to move between SE and my code. The format remains true to what was set out originally. PolyList = SiteList = the schedule.

```
def split_csv(image_df, PolyList):
    for site in PolyList:
        file_name = str(site) +'.csv'
        csv_site = image_df[image_df['PolyName'] == site]
        csv_site.to_csv(file_name, index=False, sep = ",")

split_csv(image_df, PolyList)
```

Comment: You might want to double check to make sure there aren't any weird extra spaces in the `Site` column of `image_df` or the items of `schedule`. Does `image_df[image_df['Site'] == '1B'] yield an empty dataframe? That might help narrow the issue down.

Comment: Are you sure files are not created? Since you use relative file names without folders, check the directory where this Python script resides or where ever current directory. And what is `schedule` passed into function?

Comment: @Parfait That was my mistake, schedule and SiteList are the same thing. I have edited the post to make the change. No new files are created in the directory where the script is located.

Comment: @yoskovia image_df[image_df['Site'] == '1B'] yeilds a dataframe that only contains data for Site 1B

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The edits above ended up working. The script takes a while to run, and I didn't realize that it had worked until the morning after, when all the CSV files were in the directory that I was expecting them to be in.

The code for the next person trying to do this.

```
def split_csv(image_df, PolyList):
    for site in PolyList:
        file_name = str(site) +'.csv' #str() may be unnecessary
        csv_site = image_df[image_df['PolyName'] == site] #PolyName is the site names
        csv_site.to_csv(file_name, index=False, sep = ",")

split_csv(image_df, PolyList)
```